# Track registered users content in google analytics - Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, google-analytics

I have a Joomla 2.5.9 website and I need to track what content has been read by registered users (it's a training program website).

For that, I tried to create a custom variable in Google Analytics as follows:

```
/ set custom variables
```

_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "RegisteredUsers", "{UserName}", 1]);
// track page view

A custom variable was in fact created in GA but it is useless: it just gives me the number of page views of all users.

Does anyone know how to fix the code above so I can see what pages registered users have seen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is add check for logged in users in template:

```
if (!JFactory::getUser()->guest)
{
  JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration("
    _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "RegisteredUsers", "{UserName}", 1]);
  ");
}
```

depends how you add Google Analytics tracking code (using JDocument methods or as raw template html) but concept is same.